# HMAC-SHA256 - how to?

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, hmac

I am doing HMAC-SHA256 in Android. Here is the following code :

```
String baseString = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI2NjU0MjA5MGE2NGJhYWU0MzI4NGFiYTY0MmNkNWJmNmFlNzdkNjFhIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAuaWZvcm1idWlsZGVyLmNvbS9leHphY3QvYXBpL29hdXRoL3Rva2VuIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEwNDMyMzcyLCJpYXQiOjE1MTA0MzE3NzJ9";

String clientSecret = "167edb4d9c3e603131619ae4a92c76307e3f9631";
Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
SecretKeySpec secret_key = new 
SecretKeySpec(clientSecret.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
String jwtSignature = 
Base64.encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(baseString.getBytes("UTF-8")), Base64.NO_WRAP);
Log.d("JWT-SIGNATURE", jwtSignature);
```

I get the JWT-SIGNATURE value as 2nFaU/7jcc99jTWCO0VLriN/fiLwqi/ap7eeuVhhal4=

Instead the correct JWT-SIGNATURE value should be 2nFaU_7jcc99jTWCO0VLriN_fiLwqi_ap7eeuVhhal4

There are few characters that are not correct i.e. "/" and a "=" at the end.Can someone kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding you need to use is a variant of Base64 encoding called base64url.

From wikipedia:

> Using standard Base64 in URL requires encoding of '+', '/' and '='
>   characters into special percent-encoded hexadecimal sequences ('+'
>   becomes '%2B', '/' becomes '%2F' and '=' becomes '%3D'), which makes
>   the string unnecessarily longer.
>
> For this reason, modified Base64 for URL variants exist, where the '+'
>   and '/' characters of standard Base64 are respectively replaced by '-'
>   and '_', so that using URL encoders/decoders is no longer necessary
>   and have no impact on the length of the encoded value, leaving the
>   same encoded form intact for use in relational databases, web forms,
>   and object identifiers in general. Some variants allow or require
>   omitting the padding '=' signs to avoid them being confused with field
>   separators, or require that any such padding be percent-encoded. Some
>   libraries will encode '=' to '.'.